# MySQL - Unique index on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, indexing

The idea is to make fast queries based on columns `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`.

There are 3 kinds of queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE c1=... AND c2=...
SELECT c2, c3 FROM tbl WHERE c1=...
SELECT DISTINCT c2 FROM tbl WHERE c1=... AND c3=...
```

What is the best way to build index if I want to let (`c1`, `c2`) be unique?

I'm thinking of a single index like this:

```
UNIQUE INDEX idx_c1_c2 (c1, c2)
```

But the 3rd query wouldn't be using this index.

Any suggestions?

Comment: please show also the where clause complete for the 3 query .. because is the where clause the primarly lead the indexi evaluation

Comment: Third query _will_ use the index scanning for `c1` column. Then it will scan the table for meeting `c3` condition.

Comment: @scaisEdge The `...`'s are just literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE c1= AND c2=` needs `INDEX(c1, c2)` in either order.  If that pair is "unique", then make it `UNIQUE` instead of `INDEX`.  Or consider making it be the `PRIMARY KEY` (which is also `UNIQUE` and an `INDEX`).

`WHERE c1=` will happily use any kind of index *starting* with `c1`.

`WHERE c1= AND c3=` would use only the `c1` part of `(c1, c2)`, which would be somewhat useful.  Better would be to add another index:  `INDEX(c1, c3)` in either order.  Suggest `(c3, c1)` to get some variety.

No single index will work "well" for all three queries.

Searching by `PRIMARY KEY` is usually faster than by `UNIQUE INDEX` if the table is `Engine=InnoDB`.  If you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` as the `PRIMARY KEY` now, consider whether it is worth keeping, versus replacing by the "natural" `(c1, c2)`.